# Debug TypeScript with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I created a simple TypeScript file and I have the related Source Map file generated. Also enable the Source Map in browser (Chrome, Firefox) and set a break point in my typescript file. But for some reason it just don't hit. Please suggest

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you didn't add the correct folder to the workarea in the browser? it's hard to tell without knowing your project structure a little bit.

Comment: I just update, please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: uhm.. a few more questions. Did you start chrome from VS? and if not did you add your typescript code in the Workspace tab of chrome?

Comment: I did start chrome from V2 by pressing F5

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can debug typescript in Chrome or FF this way. As far as I know, you have two options:

1. Debug the .ts file in the Chrome or FF developer tools, by enabling source mapping
2. Debug the .ts file in Visual Studio 2015, by configuring your debugger to open Internet Explorer.

Comment: I was able to debug in chrome and FF developer tools. May I know, why I won't debug in VS with chrome or FF. It works for IE only (as you mentioned).

Comment: I don't actually know the intricacies of that problem, you'd have to find out for yourself. Sorry.